# SharePoint 2010 Share Gantt chart shared between multiple sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, gantt-chart

we're looking to share a task list with a gantt chart view across multiple sites within the same site collection.
We have tried saving the web part and included data within share point designer, and then uploaded this web part on an alternative site, only to be presented with a generic error

(this method works when no gantt chart view is attached)

have tried googling etc, but unfortunately cannot find any answers..

any help or advice would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SharePoint 2010 Gantt chart you are looking for:

http://www.teamdirection.com/igwebpart/sharepoint_index.html

This can be configured to pull in any task list from your site collection into its display.